# Is Seeing Pretzus ( inappropriate image of immodest women) Yehorog vaal yavor

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, tznius-modesty, giluy-arayos

I saw on YWN someone said that the rama and shulchan aruch rule it is yeharog vaal favor any “toldos” of the 3 aveiros chamuros. However in this day in age it is very common for billboards, ads, news to have improper pictures. And it is very HARD TO ABSOLUTELY NEVER BE NICHSAL so to say it's yeharog val favor........

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Baruch and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: The Ramban (Milchamos, Sanh. 18a) indicates that יהרג ואל יעבור only extends to lavin that involve a chiyuv misa (likely including bo'eil aramis due to *kana'in pog'in bo*) or a chiyuv kareis, not to other 'arayos-related Torah prohibitions. The Shach (YD 157:10) says יהרג ואל יעבור doesn't apply to rabbinic prohibitions: "משמע דבערוה דרבנן לכ"ע יעבור ואל יהרג ופשוט הוא וכן משמע בב"י". It's a machlokes rishonim whether gazing at 'erva is a Torah prohibition (R' Yonah) or rabbinic (Rambam). In any case, R' Moshe (IM EH I, 56) holds הסתכלות בערוה is not in the category of gilui arayos at all.

Comment: R' Moshe brings proofs that it isn't 
יהרג ואל יעבור to look at an immodestly dressed woman (except in the very unusual scenario of העלה לבו טינא [Sanhedrin 75a], where R' Moshe says the cure described there is considered gilui 'arayos since it is hachana l'ma'ase z'nus). At the end of the responsum, R' Moshe says a person is permitted to go in public thoroughfares with immodestly clad people (and presumably billboards) if it is necessary to go that way, even if there is a possibility that the person will experience hirhurim or worse. But he should try to divert his attention from hirhurim.